# Nuxt generate - The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Tags: asynchronous, static, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

UPDATE: Link to Gitlab repo https://gitlab.com/daaf730/730-prismic

I'm totally lost on this one and the stacktrace is pointing me nowhere.

The error i'm getting is the one in the title saying:
`The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined`. In the picture below you'll find the complete stacktrace, as it is very hard to put into text over here.

[image: The complete stacktrace]

All my data is gathered async, just like in the example [here](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/).

Has anyone experienced something like this before and knows how to solve it?
If you need to see more code, I would gladly share it, but I just don't know which code to share .

Would love to hear from you!

~ Dave

Comment: Sharing the whole project might help 

Comment: @manniL that's a good one. Here is the link to the Gitlab repo https://gitlab.com/daaf730/730-prismic

Comment: Cloned the project and it works smooth besides some prop validation issues & some page errors on generation. Have you tried removing node modules & to reinstall these?

Comment: @manniL Thanks for trying it out! Have you tried running Nuxt Generate? That's when I get the error.

Comment: Yes, I did! Worked fine besides some errors for a few pages during generation but not the shown error above.